# deserializing json datetime yields null

Tags: json, datetime

I'm trying to deserialize a date/time from a twitter feed into Salesforce and am running into a problem where it always yields a null.

json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_at": "2021-06-12T00:00:01.000Z",
      "id": "1403502310429392901",
      "text": "She means business \uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFD‍⚖️ Gugu Mbatha-Raw is Judge Renslayer in Marvel Studios' #Loki. Stream new episodes of the Original Series every Wednesday on @DisneyPlus. https://t.co/IwpY2eUvwd"
    } ]
}
```

Deserializer from SuperFell's tool

```
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
public class Twitter_TimelineParser {
    public class Data {
        public String created_at;
        public String id;
        public String text;
    }
    
    public static Twitter_TimelineParser parse(String json) {
        return (Twitter_TimelineParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Twitter_TimelineParser.class);
    }
}
```

**created_at** always returns a null, whether I try to capture it as a DateTime, Date or String.  I really don't which type I get as long as I get the data since I can manipulate it later.

Any idea's why?

Obviously this is the compact version relying on the native parser. I've also tried with the involved one and tried to capture the string then convert it within the parser.  Still only yields null.

Thanks,

Comment: Does your `Twitter_TimelineParser` have a member called `data` that is an array of `Data`?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `data` property:

```
public class Twitter_TimelineParser {
    public class Data {
        public DateTime created_at;
        public String id;
        public String text;
    }
    public Data[] data;
    
    public static Twitter_TimelineParser parse(String json) {
        return (Twitter_TimelineParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Twitter_TimelineParser.class);
    }
}
```

Here's a demo that uses this property:

```
String jsonData = '{"data":[{"created_at": "2021-06-12T00:00:01.000Z","id": "1403502310429392901","text": "She means business \uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFD‍⚖️ Gugu Mbatha-Raw is Judge Renslayer in Marvel Studios\' #Loki. Stream new episodes of the Original Series every Wednesday on @DisneyPlus. https://t.co/IwpY2eUvwd"} ] }';
Twitter_TimelineParser result = Twitter_TimelineParser.parse(jsonData);
System.debug(result.data[0].created_at);
```

Output:

```
USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2021-06-12 00:00:01
```

We needed this extra layer because of `{ "data": [ ... ] }`, which is how we know we needed `public Data[] data;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should simply contain a List of a Map of Strings.

```
public class Twitter_TimelineParser {
    public List<Map<String,String>> data;

    public static Twitter_TimelineParser parse(String json) {
        return (Twitter_TimelineParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Twitter_TimelineParser.class);
    }
}
```

Works fine... execute anonymous proves the round trip.

```
Twitter_TimelineParser p = new Twitter_TimelineParser();

List<Map<String,String>> data = new List<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String,String> d = new Map<String,String>();
d.put('created_at','2021-06-12T00:00:01.000Z');
d.put('id','1403502310429392901');
d.put('text','some text');
data.add(d);
p.data = data;

System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(p));

System.debug(Twitter_TimelineParser.parse(JSON.serializePretty(p)));
```

Comment: Yes, you and @Phil W are correct - there's an error above from an over eager summarization during cut/paste.

Answer (score 0):

I've done more analysis and found the problem is so different than I had thought that I'm going to start a new post.  Stay tuned.